# dynamic textbox's and buttons in VB.net controls not working

Tags: vb.net

i would like to ask for help if anyone can!

i have made a sub to make dynamic textbox's and buttons.

but my problem is the follow:

i need to make the buttons add/remove 1 unit from the respective textbox's

the last 3 subs are my problem

requesting replies.

---

Public Class Form1

```
Dim IMG(9) As PictureBox
Dim lastIMG = 10
Dim leftorg = 10


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Qntorg = 115
    Dim LeftQnt = 115
    Dim TopQnt = 125

    Dim Rmvorg = 115
    Dim LeftRmv = 115
    Dim TopRmv = 145

    Dim Addorg = 135
    Dim LeftAdd = 135
    Dim TopAdd = 145

    For i = 0 To 9
        'Quantidade
        Dim tb_qt As New TextBox
        With tb_qt
            .Size = New Size(40, 20)
            .Top = TopQnt
            .Left = LeftQnt
            LeftQnt = .Left + .Width + 180
            .Text = "0"

            If .Left + .Width >= Me.Width Then
                TopQnt = .Top + 100 + 100
                .Top = TopQnt
                .Left = Qntorg
                LeftQnt = Qntorg
            End If
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(tb_qt)

        'ADD
        Dim btn_add As New Button
        With btn_add
            .Size = New Size(20, 20)
            .Top = TopAdd
            .Left = LeftAdd
            LeftAdd = .Left + .Width + 200
            .Text = "+"

            If .Left + .Width >= Me.Width Then
                TopAdd = .Top + 100 + 100
                .Top = TopAdd
                .Left = Addorg
                LeftAdd = Addorg
            End If
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(btn_add)

        'RMV
        Dim btn_rmv As New Button
        With btn_rmv
            .Size = New Size(20, 20)
            .Top = TopRmv
            .Left = LeftRmv
            LeftRmv = .Left + .Width + 200
            .Text = "-"

            If .Left + .Width >= Me.Width Then
                TopRmv = .Top + 100 + 100
                .Top = TopRmv
                .Left = Rmvorg
                LeftRmv = Rmvorg
            End If
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(btn_rmv)

        AddHandler btn_add.Click, AddressOf btn_add_Click
        AddHandler btn_rmv.Click, AddressOf btn_rmv_Click
        AddHandler tb_qt.TextChanged, AddressOf tb_qt_TextChanged
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub tb_qt_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Dim tb_qt As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

    'tb_qt.Text = c
End Sub

Public Sub btn_add_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Dim btn_add As Button = sender
    'c = c + 1
    'tb_qt_TextChanged(sender, e)
End Sub

Public Sub btn_rmv_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
```

End class

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a relationship between the `Button` and the corresponding `TextBox`.  There are a number of ways that that could be done.  One option would be to assign the `TextBox` to the `Tag` property of the `Button`, e.g.

```
btn_add.Tag = tb_qt
```

You can then get access to the `TextBox` in the `Click` event handler of the `Button` and manipulate it as you see fit, e.g.

```
Dim btn_add = DirectCast(sender, Button)
Dim tb_qt = DirectCast(btn_add.Tag, TextBox)
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually speaking as I am doing a single item but will work in a for/next too.

```
Public Sub Demo(ByVal sender As Control)

    Dim cmdDoSomething As New Button With
        {
            .Name = "cmdDoit",
            .Parent = sender,
            .Text = "Hello"
        }
    AddHandler cmdDoSomething.Click, Sub(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                         Dim b As Button = CType(s, Button)
                                         MessageBox.Show(b.Text)
                                     End Sub

    sender.Controls.Add(cmdDoSomething)


End Sub
```

Or more conventional

```
Public Sub Demo(ByVal sender As Control)

    Dim cmdDoSomething As New Button With
        {
            .Name = "cmdDoit",
            .Parent = sender,
            .Text = "Hello"
        }
    AddHandler cmdDoSomething.Click, AddressOf cmdTryToReturn_Click

    sender.Controls.Add(cmdDoSomething)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdTryToReturn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(CType(sender, Button).Text)
End Sub
```

Hope this is what you are looking for and if not steers you in the right direction.

One more thing, if you need to associate a button to a text box consider working that into the tag property of the newly created button.